# Going from Navigation controller to ModalViewController is not working and crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my project i have used navigation controller to move to another but i have some view in which there is my custom navigation controller.

Please suggest me what should i do ?

I have tried doing like this but is occurring crash for me.

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myVechileView animated:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:myVechileView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you define the modal view controller?

Comment: Paste the Crash Log ??

Comment: Thanks guys i had made mistake while dragging file the xib was not loaded in the bundle resource.I have solved it by going in Project >>Copy Bundle resource >> and added the nib there.

Comment: Guys but still i have one problem actually in my whole application i have used navigation controller except of in "myVechileView" i have custom tab bar in the bottom which i am using in all of the view.Now what is happening going from navigation controller to presentviewcontroller the tab bar button stops working In "MyVechileView".

Comment: describe your whole application flow

Comment: Actually in my whole application i have used Navigation controller to go to next view.But in "myVechileView" i have already placed navigation controller in the nib which has its bar button.My Problem is i have one customTabBarButton View which i am using in every view bottom.But here in myVechileView these button is not working because there i am using navigation controller to go to next view. tell me any solution how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:myVechileView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

presentModalViewController:animated: takes a [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) not a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are useing  iOS 6 then use this..

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:myVechileView animated:YES completion:nil];'
```

and if you are ruing on iOS 5 then

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myVechileView animated:YES];
```

hope this help you